# How does "see" work in the method docs?

Tags: visual-studio

```
/// <summary>
/// Get all following siblings of each element up to but not including the element matched by the selector.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="selector">A string containing a selector expression to indicate where to stop matching following sibling elements.</param>
/// <see cref="http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/"/>
/// <returns></returns>
public SharpQuery NextUntil(string selector = null)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

I wanted to add a link in my method docs to link to a fuller explanation. "see" seemed appropriate for this (intellisense suggested it). However, when I call start typing my method, "see" doesn't appear in the tooltip. Is there a way to go to that link? I tried pressing F1, it [took me to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28VS.TEXTEDITOR%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION%3dV4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true) instead.

Answer (score 1):

The `<see>` tag must be used within the text of other comment tags in order to specify a hyperlink.

You can also use `<seealso>` to specify a hyperlink to appear in a See Also section of the generated documentation.

MSDN provides the following example:

```
/// text for class TestClass
public class TestClass
{
    /// <summary>DoWork is a method in the TestClass class.
    /// <para>Here's how you could make a second paragraph in a description. <see cref="System.Console.WriteLine(System.String)"/> for information about output statements.</para>
    /// <seealso cref="TestClass.Main"/>
    /// </summary>
    public static void DoWork(int Int1)
    {
    }

    /// text for Main
    static void Main()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay...that creates a reference to a method, but how do I link to a website then?

Comment: What tool are you using to generate documentation from the XML files? I believe GhostDoc works with either <seealso href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Ask for help</seealso> or simply <a href="http://www.google.com">Try a web search</a>

Comment: None. Wanted it to appear within Visual Studio intellisense.

Comment: @Mark: I don't think that's supported. The HTML markup would be supported in the output of most document generation tools, but Intellisense appears to strip out any markup tags.

Answer (score 1):

From what I gathered at:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ast78ax(VS.80).aspx
This tags ( , ) will be available in the generated documentation file (the XML file, when you do /doc compiler options), and then further processed by tool like [Sandcastle](http://sandcastle.codeplex.com/)